# Custom Add-In Toolbar to stack

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that generates a custom toolbar. My issue is, as I add more buttons/pop ups, they ad one another horizontally. which means after adding 4/5 it tends to take up a huge amount. Is there a way these can be stacked in a vertical list of 3 like in the Menu Commands bar?

```
Sub CreateMyMenu()
    Dim myCB As CommandBar
    Dim myCBtn1 As CommandBarButton
    Dim myCBtn2 As CommandBarButton
    Dim myCPup1 As CommandBarPopup
    Dim myCPup2 As CommandBarPopup
    Dim myCP1Btn1 As CommandBarButton
    Dim myCP1Btn2 As CommandBarButton

    ' Delete the CommandBar if it exists already
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars("MyMenu").Delete

    ' Create a new CommandBar
    Set myCB = CommandBars.Add(Name:="MyMenu", Position:=msoBarFloating)

    ' Add button 1 to this bar
    Set myCBtn1 = myCB.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With myCBtn1
     .Caption = "1st Button"
     .Style = msoButtonCaption   '<- force caption text to show on your button
    End With

    ' Add popup menu 1 to this bar - this is a menu that folds out
    Set myCPup1 = myCB.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    myCPup1.Caption = "Statistics"

    ' Add button 1 to popup menu 1
    Set myCP1Btn1 = myCPup1.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With myCP1Btn1
     .Style = msoButtonAutomatic
     .FaceId = 487
    End With

    ' Add button 2 to popup menu 1
    Set myCP1Btn1 = myCPup1.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With myCP1Btn1
     .Caption = "Click me!"
     .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
     .FaceId = 59
     .OnAction = "SubItworks"    '<- call the sub routine SubItWorks
    End With

    ' Add a second button to this bar
    Set myCBtn2 = myCB.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With myCBtn2
     .FaceId = 17  ' <- Face Id 17 is a barchart icon
     .Caption = "Barchart"    '<- shows when hovering mouse over icon
    End With

    ' Add popup menu 1 to this bar - this is a menu that folds out
    Set myCPup1 = myCB.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    myCPup1.Caption = "Settings"


    ' Show the command bar
    myCB.Visible = True
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub SubItWorks()
    MsgBox ("Eureka, it works!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the following it works:

```
CommandBars.Add
```

to

```
CommandBars.Button.Add
```

Answer (score 0):

Review this sample :

[image]

VBA codes :

```
Sub Workbook_Commandbar()
'create the menubar
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim MyBar As CommandBar
Dim MyButton1, MyButton2 As CommandBarButton
Dim MyList As CommandBarComboBox

On Error Resume Next
Application.CommandBars("Sheet_Navigate").Delete    'If the command bar was created before, it is deleted.
On Error GoTo 0

Set MyBar = CommandBars.Add("Sheet_Navigate", , False, True)
With MyBar

Set MyButton1 = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)      
With MyButton1
            .Caption = "Update"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .BeginGroup = True
            .OnAction = "Update_Lst"           
End With

Set MyButton2 = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)   
With MyButton2
            .Caption = "A-Z"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .BeginGroup = True
            .OnAction = "Sort"                  
End With
...
```

[Source,sample file address](https://eksi30.com/create-new-command-bar-using-macro/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a late answer, but i figured a way to "stack" buttons.
You will have to create multiple commandbars and add just one button/control to it.

```
Set customBar = Application.CommandBars.Add("1"): customBar.Visible = True
Call bar_button(customBar, _
                "Join duplicate rows", _
                "join_dup", _
                "This tool joins rows that relate to the same piece of data (ex:""ID"", ""Case"", ""Vendor"", etc.) into one", _
                452)

Function bar_button(customBar As CommandBar, but_cap As String, macro_name As String, tooltiptext As String, faceid As Long)

Set newButton = customBar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
newButton.Caption = but_cap
newButton.Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
newButton.OnAction = macro_name
newButton.faceid = faceid
newButton.tooltiptext = tooltiptext
    
End Function
```

It will look like this

[image]

Comment: While I don't know what the VBA would be (I usually use XML directly), you can also add them to [a box element, with `boxStyle="vertical"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/fb660d68-051e-4a86-ab97-e0d93b32817e)

Comment: Correct, that would be the correct solution but from vba those type of objects cannot be created inside commandbars.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msocontroltype